# How to work safely on a MongoDB with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I started working today on a MongoDB with pymongo but I must not modify its elements. So I searched how to copy such DB but I didn't quite understand where and from where the database is copyed in [this documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/copydb.html).

I think the simplest and safest way is to work on a local copy but I don't understand how to do it.

(FYI I'm working with pymongo on Windows 7)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [mongodump & mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#binary-bson-dumps).

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is actually very useful. I found a lot of documentation on deprecated methods. Mongodump & mongorestore feel much easier to understand and safe for safe for a newcomer.